# An asset cannot be written to a location outside the project - angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm totaly confused right now. I'm not able to use `ng serve` anymore since i upgraded the Angular-CLI to > 1.5.3 because of the error i get:

> An asset cannot be written to a location outside the project

So i tried to do a downgrade, i did it like this:

1. npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. npm uninstall -g angular-cli
3. npm cache clean --force
4. restarted windows pc
5. npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.3

i did this three times and everytime i check which version is installed after i reinstalled the cli, it is 1.5.4 - i'm realy angry about this and don't know, what i'm doing wrong.

It's a known error in Versions higher than 1.5.3, you can have a look at it over here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8613

so please, how can i install and use angular-cli at version 1.5.3

Comment: Have you tried any versions of the CLI higher than 1.5.4? 1.6.7 came out this week. Are you forced to use 1.5.3?

Comment: the issue is still not fixed so i have to use a version lower than 1.5.4 :-/

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using? Are you running the install as admin or root? And, did you update the CLI in the application, too? Installing globally is one thing, locally is another.

Answer (score -1):

Please note, you may manually Copy node_modules\ng2-pdfjs-viewer\pdfjs to your public or asset folder or use any copy script as part of your build process.

Worked for me

Have you seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer#step-2-copy-task-for-pdfjs